# "The more often — the better." Is it possible to say that?

Tags: meaning, phrases

The meaning I want to show with this phrase is that you do something more times and it produces better results. Is "the more often — the better" correct? Or maybe there are any set expressions instead of this?

Comment: Better to use *correct* or *grammatical* than *possible* because, really, it's possible to say anything at all; nothing stops you!

Comment: ...*rather than *possible* because...

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would stylize it:

> "You should do this -- the more often, the better."

Other phrases that mean similar things:

> You should do this as often as possible.
>
> The more you do this, the better the results.
>
> Results scale with use -- the more, the better

Etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, “the more often, the better” is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A common expression suitable here is *practice makes perfect*.

*The more [often], the better* and other variants just sound like bad translations to me. They distractingly call to mind *the more the merrier*, which obviously isn't what's meant.

Comment: There are plenty of common expressions on this pattern that sound completely natural, for instance: *Go get me a rope - the longer, the better*.

Comment: I agree sentences like your example are common and well-formed. But I'm having trouble seeing how OP's context could be re-cast into one like that. If you asked your piano teacher how much you should practice, then yes - "*the more, the better*" is just about "sayable". But it still sounds weird to me. I'd be happy to say "*the more you do, the better you'll get*", but the short form just comes across as a failed attempt to coin a maxim.